# SQL Query notification: STRING and INT64 at [5:8]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wanted to run this query to get a list of stations Subscribers use. I was following along with an inner query tutorial on google Coursera tech certification course 5 week 3 and the syntax for the query matches everything on the screen with my big query editor.  However, the results on the course tutorial screen doesn't show the error message I get.

```sql
SELECT
station_id,
name 
 FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
 WHERE station_id IN
 (
   SELECT start_station_id
   FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
   WHERE 
   usertype = 'Subscriber'
 )
```

Message:

> Cannot execute IN subquery with uncomparable types STRING and
> INT64 at [5:8]

I looked up the error message on google.  I couldn't find the definition of the terms in the error message.  I reached out to cohorts in the field on my Linked In account and can't receive a response before my homework is due.  I checked the syntax multiple times comparing it with the tutorial screen in my lesson.  There is no difference in the syntaxes.  The only difference seems to be in the result where I get this error message and the tutorial screen does not.

Comment: my guess usertype  is int64 and not string, but you shoul add the table columns with type an you will also have a type table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message clearly indicates that `station_id` in `citibike_stations` and `start_station_id` in `citibike_trips` have different types.

If you are sure that you copied query correctly it's quite possible you created tables earlier on with wrong types.

Check definition of your tables: most likely both columns `station_id` and `start_station_id` should be of type `INT64`